# Formatting Axis of a graph

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am using the below VBA to set the Y axes format of my graph and it works fine

**Code:**

```
TrendGraph.Axes(2, 1).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
```

The problem happens when changing it to time:-

**Code**

```
TrendGraph.Axes(2, 1).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "hh:nn:ss"
```

**I get the same issue with currency:**

```
TrendGraph.Axes(2, 1).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "Currency"
TrendGraph.Axes(2, 1).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "£0.00"
```

Error Received:

> Automation Error: Object is not connected to the server

Any help is appreciated

Comment: But your time value is not a number; neither is the formatted time value (using Format). What happens if you just omit setting the property?

Comment: Without setting a property the axes shows 0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1

Comment: That looks like the rounded numerical value of hours through Noon. Try to apply Format in the source to convert the values to text so text is passed to the graph.